# Python - C Compile errors - gcc failed

Tags: python, gcc, pip

Oftentimes when I try to install a Python package, installation will fail with following error: "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1".

I am at loss. Most things I try to instal fail. I am losing my mind on this. Really like the language, but this is driving me crazy. Spent countless hours looking for solutions, to no avail.

Probably the problem comes from my environment. Here's how I am (insanely?) trying to run things:

Windows 7 machine 
MS Visual C++ 14 redist freshly installed
Python 2.7.15 through Jupyter/SageMath 8.3 (can't execute Python through Console because throws 16bit error)

P.s.: I'm an ignorant, but I know it, so don't bother. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have gcc installed?

Comment: *because throws 16bit error* Because **what**?

Comment: Why don't you use just install Python from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @John don't know how to check for that. Some modules do install allright so I would guess yes though.

Comment: @Elliott because *it* throws a 16 bit error (~"16 bit app not supported").

Comment: @Red Cricket Because the Jupyter interface is convenient for what little I have to do. But if it's my bottleneck, that's another story.

Comment: I have been use PyCharm (free version) its kind of nice and simple to use.

Comment: Where / how did you get a 16-bit version of python? Or was that gcc? What package are you trying to install?

Comment: It's the kernel bundled into SageMath.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround/solution.

I am suspecting that the Python kernel provided with SageMath is not a 100% complete/functional Python kernel/core. I reluctantly conceded to install a standalone Python "kernel" (not certain the term is technically correct) from Python.org, v. 2.7.15, using the standard prebuilt binaries for x64 Windows systems. Installed it in a different folder than Sage of course, added it to the system Path variable, and guess what? Yeah, issues resolved. Everything now installs flawlessly - well, mostly, but at least now it's down to an acceptable level of failure. So I installed Jupyter on this kernel and I can now continue my development the way I like it.

I mean, I would if a few hundred lines of code weren't too many for the computer on which I am working... Since it's lagging a bit, I will need to resort to other 'IDE' solutions. But that's another story altogether...

Thanks much nonetheless to everybody who bothered dropping a line by. Especially @Red Cricket, who helped me reconsider my reluctancy to install another Python kernel alongside SageMath's. Not a big fan of duplication, but hey, enough time lost there.